# How to write solid Pure Aggregation (composition) Game Objects in Java?

Tags: java, interface, game-engine, composition

So I am just at the beginning of writing a game in Java and I am writing my game objects. Now I have read here in [Evolve Your Hierarchy](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/) that you should build your games as compositions and not as a big class hierarchy. As this image from the previous link shows:

[image]

However, when actually getting down to the implementation I have one small question about where to apply the interfaces.

Lets say you have a class called Player and the interfaces Moveable and Renderable. Do you implement this using public interface variables:

```
class Player {
    public Moveable moveable;
    public Renderable renderable;
}

class GenericMoveable implements Moveable {
    // Function implementations
}

class PlayerRenderable implements Renderable {
    // Function implementations
}
```

Or do you try and do this by applying the interfaces directly to the object:

```
class Player implements Moveable, Renderable {
    private GenericMoveable genericMoveable;

    // Non-direct Implementation of Moveable
    void someMoveFunc(double x, double y) {
        genericMoveable.someMoveFunc(x, y);
    }

    // Direct implementation of Renderable
    void someRenderableFunction() {
        // Player class specific code
    }
}

class GenericMoveable implements Moveable {
    // Function implementations
}
```

Now currently I am feeling that the second method is better. The main reason for that is because I can create the following lists:

```
List<Renderable> renderObjects; // use this to draw all of the objects to the screen
List<Moveable> moveObjects; // use this to move all objects at once
```

I really just want confirmation that I am on the right track. I am pretty sure that when creating game objects by composition for games in Java you want to apply the interfaces directly to the Game Object in question and then use private interfaces if you need them and direct implementations of those functions for the rest. Is this correct? And what are the positives and negatives of what I am doing?

Though, while we are here, what else do I need to look out for in the implementation of Compositional Game Objects in Java? What should I do differently? Thanks for any responses in advance, I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: The second example seems a lot nicer because you're able to make lists from the Moveable and Renderable interfaces. However, I have a number of classes that implement Moveable and I find I duplicate the genericMoveable.someMoveFunc(x, y); in all of them - did you run into this problem?

Comment: @sdasdadas Actually I would recommend taking a look at this: http://gamadu.com/artemis/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting link. I gather that what you have in mind for your `Player` class is what that article calls a component container. For that, applying the interfaces to the class sounds to me like the way to go. It's the only route that will lead you to a pure aggregation structure (where there is no longer a `Player` class *per se* in your system.

By the way, the structure you're proposing is basically an application of the [delegation design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern). A `Player` relies delegates to a `Movement` object all movement operations and it doesn't care what specific kind of `Movement` object it has to work with.

Comment: I should really commit more design patterns to memory so that I can explain my thoughts better. "It's the only route that will lead you to a pure aggregation structure" So does that mean that the structure is not currently what was meant by a pure aggregation?

Comment: Not from what I understood of that link. He writes, "...each game entity is comprised of a collection of components. There is no 'game entity object' as such." I take him to mean exactly that: there would be no `Player` class at all in a pure aggregation architecture. It's a fairly extreme refactoring and I got the impression from what he wrote that the journey there wasn't exactly pain-free for him. Going partway (like you're doing) seems much more reasonable to me.

Answer (score 4):

I have created a few games using java and have also seen the source to a few very good games and it seems the most common way of doing this is with the second method. From what I can tell, the best reason to use the second method is because it becomes easier to keep track of your objects using Lists and allows you to draw using less lines. It seems you are on the right track and the Evolve Your Hierarchy article is a great read for new game developers.

Comment: Well if you have seen it in the wild then that gives me more confidence that this path at least works well enough for others to use.