# Is there a way to use the Delegation design pattern without losing substitutability in Java?

Tags: java, composition, aggregation, liskov-substitution-principle

This question refers to the **Delegation** design pattern found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern).

I have a number of interfaces for my game engine representing various entities:

- Player
- Vehicle
- Mesh
- etc.

and each one of these can be rendered, so they implement the Renderable interface which contains the method `render()`.

**METHOD 1**

Using delegation, an example looks like this:

```
public interface Vehicle {

    public void drive();

}

public class Car implements Vehicle {

    public Renderable renderable;

    @Override
    public void drive() { // ... }

}
```

Whenever I want to render a car, I just call `car.renderable.render();`.

The problem with this method is that I cannot create a List and iterate through it.

**METHOD 2**

To solve this, I could have Vehicle extend Renderable:

```
public interface Vehicle extends Renderable {

    public void drive();

}
```

but the problem with this is that if I define Car, Bicycle, Truck, Tank, etc. each of these classes will have to fill in the code for render() (which will probably be identical).

Is there a way to maintain the benefits of extending Renderable in my Vehicle interface without being forced to define render() in all of my concrete classes implementing Vehicle?

Comment: This question came from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546711/how-to-write-solid-pure-aggregation-composition-game-objects-in-java

Comment: Does each class that holds a Renderable have a `public Renderable getRenderable()` method? And if so, couldn't this be made into an interface allowing you to hold a collection of these beasts? Also, are you having these guys implement the Iterable interface?

Comment: Each does have a 'getRenderable()' method. I believe that I can just extract an interface (although I'm not sure what to call it, since it's basically just a test for the actual Renderable interface). And no, I wasn't going to...

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I've made an edit - is that what you mean? It still seems a bit verbose because I would have to make two interfaces for each "property".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding my comment,

> Does each class that holds a Renderable have a public Renderable getRenderable() method? And if so, couldn't this be made into an interface allowing you to hold a collection of these beasts?

I was meaning something like this:

```
interface Renderable {
   void render();
}

interface RenderDelegator {
   Renderable getRenderable();
   void setRenderable(Renderable renderable);
}

abstract class Vehicle implements RenderDelegator {
   private Renderable renderable;

   @Override
   public Renderable getRenderable() {
      return renderable;
   }

   @Override
   public void setRenderable(Renderable renderable) {
      this.renderable = renderable;
   }

   public abstract void drive();
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
   @Override
   public void drive() {
      // TODO finish!
   }

}
```

And nix that suggestion about implementing Iterable. I'm not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: That's cool and fulfills everything I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: @sdasdadas: you're welcome, but note that I'm not a design patterns maven. Keep an eye on this thread and if a better suggestion comes along, let us know and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be to separate the concept of a Renderable object from its possible delegate renderer; in this way, you have the option of delegating to a common renderer or implementing the render() method right in a class, if your renderer code is specific to a single class.

Thinking further along, your renderer may need to query the instance of whatever entity it's trying to render -- imagine your Vehicle has methods to get its position on a map, and the renderer needs to get at those values in order to render it in the correct position; that's why the Renderer interface receives an instance of a Renderable.

```
interface Renderable {
    void render();
}

interface Vehicle extends Renderable {
    void drive();
}

interface Renderer<T extends Renderable> {
    void render(T renderable);
}

public class VehicleRenderer implements Renderer<Vehicle> {
    public void Render(Vehicle renderable) {
        // TODO: Render a Vehicle.
    }
}

public class Car implements Vehicle {
    private Renderer<Vehicle> renderer;

    public void setRenderer(Renderer<Vehicle> renderer) {
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }

    public void render() {
        renderer.render(this);
    }

    public void drive() {
        // TODO: Drive the car.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code for the `render` method will be identical among different classes, then do the following:

Introduce an abstract class called `AbstractRenderable` that implements `Renderable`.  Then have the `Car`, `Bicycle`, etc. classes extend `AbstractRenderable` and implement `Vehicle` (or `Player`, etc.).

In the `AbstractRenderable` class, implement the `render` method.  That way, all Cars, Bicycles, etc. rely on the "identical" render code.  Plus, if the render code does differ on a `Tank` for example, you can simply override the `render` method.

Comment: This works until I need to extend from more than just Renderable (sorry, I should have stated that I would like to add Moveable, Destroyable, etc. in the future).